# why I get TypeError when I unpack my **kwargs in python

Tags: python, typeerror, keyword-argument

I have pasted a short portion of my code that is relevant to my question.
I am passing a `dict` to the `itemSearch` method of my class, but I get a `TypeError`

```
def itemsearch(self,*args,**params):
        #items = self.api.item_search('Books', Publisher="O'Reilly", Author="James Shore",Year="2014",limit=10)
        print args
        print params
        itemSearch=self.api.item_search(*args,**params)
        print [item.ASIN for items in itemSearch.Items.Item]
        self.listASIN=[(item.Title,item.ASIN) for items in itemSearch.Items.Item]

amazonsearch=AmazonLookup()
params={'SearchIndex':'Electronics','Condition':'New','Keywords':'Macbook pro 13 retina','MinimumPrice':'600',
        'MaximumPrice':'2000','Sort':'-price'}
print params
amazonsearch.itemsearch(**params)
```

I get `TypeError: item_search() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: can you show full traceback? also `item_search()` != `itemsearch()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
itemSearch = self.api.item_search(*args, **params)
```

Apparently, the `item_search` function requires a positional argument first. Positional arguments are filled from `args` but `args` is an empty list as you call the `itemsearch` function only with a unpacked dictionary:

```
amazonsearch.itemsearch(**params)
```

So you need to provide at least that first parameter too (like in your commented-out example: `'Books'`).

Comment: this one actually worked; `api.item_search('Blended', Keywords='Keanu Reaves')`